# Tomcat SSL: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, pki

I'm trying to access an url in my application, but I'm getting this error.

```
1771426 [http-bio-8180-exec-15] ERROR gadget.GadgetValidatorServlet  - wsdl.exception.WSInvokerException: wsdl.exception.WSInvokerException: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
1771426 [http-bio-8180-exec-15] ERROR gadget.GadgetPortalValidatorServlet  - gadget.exception.GadgetValidatorException: wsdl.exception.WSInvokerException: wsdl.exception.WSInvokerException: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I've tried to apply all of those fixes but with no success:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

Shortly it needs to run InstallCert app (java InstallCert my.domain.com) and generate the file jssecacerts. After that I've copied and paste this file into /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts

I've also import my cert, the same used in my ssl url (httpd) into my keystore used by tomcat.

Even after that I still getting this error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should have imported it into the *truststore* used by Tomcat.

Comment: I've imported it into my keystore, which I imported in tomcat connect configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to fix this problem in the past by setting the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` system property at runtime to point to the `jssecacerts` file. Just putting it in the "right" place never worked for me; I had to set the location explicitly. This is more portable anyway, so I recommend it in general if your app ever needs to move around.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/to/jssecacerts");
```